# Diferença de desempenho absurda entre pygame.surfarray.array3d e array2d

Tags: array, python-3.x, desempenho, numpy, pygame

Usando o `pygame.surfarray` para controlar uma imagem como um array, a manipulação de qualquer elemento em um `array3d` é **mais de 5 vezes mais lenta** do que manipular um elemento `array2d`.

Veja este benchmark:

```
from datetime import *
import pygame

image = pygame.image.load('8000x8000.png')
arr = pygame.surfarray.array3d(image)

start = datetime.now()
for y in range(8000):
    for x in range(8000):
        if arr[x, y, 0] != 0:
            pass

end = datetime.now()
print(end - start)
```

No caso acima, uma imagem de 8000 x 8000 é lida pixel a pixel.

`array3d` retorna os elementos neste formato: [R, G, B]. Ex: `(255, 255, 255)` = Branco.

No exemplo acima, o processamento de elementos 8000 ^ 2 usando array3d leva o tempo total: `0:01:41.996732`

Agora, fazendo exatamente o mesmo, apenas mudando para `array2d`:

```
...
    arr = pygame.surfarray.array2d(image)
...    
            if arr[x, y] != 0:

...
```

O tempo total é: `0:00:20.632741`, ou seja, **mais de 5 vezes mais rápido**.

Porque isso?